# Order of Layers in Folium

Tags: python, folium

I am working on creating a map where I am using weather data, as well as overlaying images to show where things are. My problem is that the ImageOverlay raster layer is always below the polygons (if there is overlap). Is there a way to have the ImageOverlay layer be above the polygon?

Here is an example of what I am talking about which can be put into a jupyter notebook and be ran (assuming you have the necessary packages installed)

```
import folium
m = folium.Map([37, 0], zoom_start=1, tiles="stamentoner")

folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay(
    image="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f4/Mercator_projection_SW.jpg",
    name="I am a jpeg",
    bounds=[[-82, -180], [82, 180]],
    opacity=1,
    interactive=False,
    cross_origin=False,
    zindex=1,
    alt="Wikipedia File:Mercator projection SW.jpg",
).add_to(m)
polygon = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -87.01171875,
              40.3130432088809
            ],
            [
              -86.7041015625,
              35.639441068973944
            ],
            [
              -79.4970703125,
              35.53222622770337
            ],
            [
              -79.716796875,
              40.38002840251183
            ],
            [
              -87.01171875,
              40.3130432088809
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
geo_j  = folium.GeoJson(polygon)
geo_j.add_to(m)
m
```

In this example, the polygon would be completely behind the raster and would not be of benefit, but I would like some help figuring it out.

Comment: Have you tried switching the order of adding layers to the map ?

Comment: It has been long enough since I have done anything with this that I don't know what I tried. Can you provide the solution you suggested to my example where this works if it does?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [keep_in_front()](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.folium.Map.keep_in_front) method to keep the desired layer in front.

Comment: I made this question a long time ago and I don't remember the exact details of what I tried, but I am pretty sure that I had tried using the keep_in_front() method and I did not have any results. Can you provide the solution to the example I gave?